# Filtering with dynamic criteria to exclude some values in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

I have a data array of strings:

```
0:"dbname_default_2018-10-26"
1:"dbname_default_2018-10-27"
2:"dbname_default_2018-10-28"
3:"dbname_default_2018-10-30"
4:"dbname_default_2018-10-31"
5:"dbname_default_2018-11-01"
6:"dbname_default_2018-11-03"
7:"dbname_default_2018-11-04"
8:"dbname_default_2018-11-06"
9:"dbname_default_2018-11-07"
10:"dbname_default_2018-11-08"
```

…and another array of criteria, which is dynamically created with `formatDate`:

```
0:"2018-11-06"
1:"2018-11-07"
```

I would like to splice items where the name includes the criteria. The goal is to delete database names depending on seniority days. So if seniority is 2, it should only keep items with date is today-2days and older.

Here's my program:

```
async function selectDdToDelete(dbArray, seniority) {
    let datesToKeep: string[] = [];
    let dbTokeep;
    for (let i = seniority; i >= 0; i--) {
        datesToKeep.push(
            `${formatDate(i).year}-${formatDate(i).month}-${formatDate(i).day}`
        );
    }
    dbTokeep = dbArray.filter(elm => {
        let exists = false;
        for (let i = 0; i < datesToKeep.length; i++) {
            if (elm.includes(datesToKeep[i])) {
                exists = true;
            }
        }
        if (!exists) {
            return elm;
        }
    });

    return dbTokeep;
}
```

I'm getting firstly an array of criteria with `formatDate()` which sends me an object `{year:2018,month:"11",day:"06"}`, for example if `i==1` ( today date -i).

Then I'm filtering on the data array. Inside it, I loop the array criteria and with an intermediate variable, I decide wether I return the element or not.

Then I send the new filtered array.

My problem is that actually I get the same array in entry that at the end.

What I expect to get is:

```
0:"dbname_default_2018-10-26"
1:"dbname_default_2018-10-27"
2:"dbname_default_2018-10-28"
3:"dbname_default_2018-10-30"
4:"dbname_default_2018-10-31"
5:"dbname_default_2018-11-01"
6:"dbname_default_2018-11-03"
7:"dbname_default_2018-11-04"
8:"dbname_default_2018-11-08"
```

Comment: How does `formatDate` work? Can you include it in your code example?

Comment: Just an optimization, but you can directly try `datesToKeep.join('|').includes(...)`. It will save you the effort of looping again. Also, returning `elm` if not match doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Rajesh not exactly an optimization. Sure it will make the code more concise but then you'll have to extract the date substring out of each entry and `includes()` will attempt to match starting from every string character rather than every date string in the aggregate string.

Comment: @PatrickHund I have added an explanation about `formatDate` function

Comment: Array.filter is supposed to return a boolean, not an array element. Can you try fixing that and see if your code works, then?

Comment: that's it ! thank you so much. Now if there is a way to optimise that and make code more readable that would be cool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var data = [
"dbname_default_2018-10-26",
"dbname_default_2018-10-27",
"dbname_default_2018-10-28",
"dbname_default_2018-10-30",
"dbname_default_2018-10-31",
"dbname_default_2018-11-01",
"dbname_default_2018-11-03",
"dbname_default_2018-11-04",
"dbname_default_2018-11-06",
"dbname_default_2018-11-07",
"dbname_default_2018-11-08" ]

const dynamicCretarias = [
  "2018-11-06",
  "2018-11-07"
];

data = data.filter((item)=> !dynamicCretarias.some(t => item.includes(t)))
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try to make a set of cretaria elements and then filter your data array

```
const data = [
"dbname_default_2018-10-26",
"dbname_default_2018-10-27",
"dbname_default_2018-10-28",
"dbname_default_2018-10-30",
"dbname_default_2018-10-31",
"dbname_default_2018-11-01",
"dbname_default_2018-11-03",
"dbname_default_2018-11-04",
"dbname_default_2018-11-06",
"dbname_default_2018-11-07",
"dbname_default_2018-11-08"
];

const dynamicCretarias = [
  "2018-11-06",
  "2018-11-07"
];

const dynamicCretariasSet = dynamicCretarias.reduce((set, item) => {
  return set.add(data.find(dataEl => dataEl.includes(item)))
}, new Set());

const filtered = data.filter(item => !dynamicCretariasSet.has(item));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to *exclude* items from an array of strings based on if the element contains one of the strings from some criteria array.

I would suggest using the following functions: [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

`findIndex` can be used to determine if any of the criteria match a given element from your data array.

`filter` allows you to test each element of the data array and only keeps the ones you want.

```js
let data = [
  "dbname_default_2018-10-26",
  "dbname_default_2018-10-27",
  "dbname_default_2018-10-28",
  "dbname_default_2018-10-30",
  "dbname_default_2018-10-31",
  "dbname_default_2018-11-01",
  "dbname_default_2018-11-03",
  "dbname_default_2018-11-04",
  "dbname_default_2018-11-06",
  "dbname_default_2018-11-07",
  "dbname_default_2018-11-08"
]

let criteria = ["2018-10-26","2018-10-27"]

let results = data.filter( element => criteria.findIndex( crit => element.includes(crit))<0)

console.log(results)
```